# Binding Listbox to bindinglist, filter on item property

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, listbox, bindinglist

I'm working on a Winforms application and I have a bindinglist of objects that I want to bind to a listbox.  I got this to work, but what I want to do next, is only display items where a particular property is true.

So I have a class with a bindinglist

```
class DataBuilder
{    
    public BindingList<TableSet> allTableSets = new BindingList<TableSet>();
}
```

And a class `TableSet` with some properties

```
class TableSet
{
    public string TableSetName {get; set;}
    public bool IsPopulated {get; set;}
}
```

And now on my form, I want to bind a listbox to the allTableSets, but only show the items where  `IsPopulated == true`

What I have so far on my form just shows all the items in the allTableSets list

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    DataBuilder dataBuilder = new DataBuilder();
    {
        this.populatedTableSetsListBox.DataSource = dataBuilder.allTableSets;
        this.populatedTableSetsListBox.DisplayMember = "TableSetName";
    }
}
```

I've been looking around the web but haven't found anything that seems similar to what I"m trying to do.  Any suggestions or alternate methods are greatly appreciated.  Thank you

Comment: this data that is being Bound are you running a query of some sort..? if so then Change the Query and add a `Where` clause `WHERE IsPopulated = true`

Comment: @DJ KRAZE - No in my `class DataBuilder` I instantiate several `TabeleSets` that each hold different data via DataTables.  I have other code that populates the DataTables via queries to a database, and when a query is finished, I update the `IsPopulated` property for the `TableSet`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this: in your `DataBuilder` class, have a function that returns a subset of your items based on your filter condition.

For example, in your `DataBuilder` class:

```
    public BindingList<TableSet> someTableSets()
    {
        BindingList<TableSet> someTableList = new BindingList<TableSet>();
        foreach (TableSet TS in allTableSets)
            if (TS.IsPopulated == true)
                someTableList.Add(TS);
        return someTableList;
    }
```

Then, in your `MainForm`, instead of setting the `DataSource` to `allTableSets`, set it equal to the result of the `someTableSets()` function:

```
    this.populatedTableSetsListBox.DataSource = dataBuilder.someTableSets();
```

Comment: I think you meant   someTableList.Add(TS)