# Bind to subset of bindinglist

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-2.0

I have a datagridviewComboBoxColumn. I want each of its cells to have as possible values a **subset** of a bindinglist (let's call it the "master" bindinglist).
One suggestion I found online was this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14820929

But the items in the original bindinglist will be constantly changing (new items added, old ones removed). Is there any way to make the cells' items be automatically updated when the "master" binding list is changed?

Answer (score 0):

You could see if a [FilteredObservableCollection](https://code.google.com/p/fap/source/browse/trunk/FAP.Foundation/FilteredObservableCollection.cs?r=104) fits your needs. It's really for WPF but you could take the concept and adapt it for BindingLists.

You can have as many filtered wrappers as you want around a single master list and each one acts like a separate list, operating (and notifiying) only on the subset that matches a filter you supply.